# Odoo Manufacturing Picking - Show lots having quantity greater than zero 0

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-11, odoo-12

I have added a lot quantity field in Manufacturing picking operations. It is reflecting the lot quantity perfectly with respect to location. Now the problem is I do not want to show the lots having no product i.e. 0 quantity. How do I achieve this?

Here is the screenshot where I want to make changes.[image]

Here is the model code (stock_move_line.py):

```py
class StockMoveLine(models.Model):
    _name = "stock.move.line"
    _description = "Product Moves (Stock Move Line)"
    _rec_name = "product_id"
    _order = "result_package_id desc, id"
    lot_id = fields.Many2one('stock.production.lot', 'Lot/Serial Number123')
    x_lot_qty = fields.Float(compute="fetch_lot_wrt_location", 
                       name="Lot Quantity", 
                       store=True,
                       readonly=True, 
                       digits=(12,3))
    
    @api.onchange('lot_id','location_id')
    def fetch_lot_wrt_location(self):
        self.x_lot_qty = 0.0
        for row in self:
            quants = self.env['stock.quant'].search([('lot_id.id','=',row.lot_id.id)])
            for quant in quants:
                if row.location_id.display_name == quant.location_id.display_name:
                    row.x_lot_qty = quant.quantity
```

Here are the views (stock_move_views.xml):

```xml
<field name="lot_id" 
            attrs="{'readonly': ['&amp;', ('package_level_id', '!=', False), ('parent.picking_type_entire_packs', '=', True)]}" 
            invisible="not context.get('show_lots_m2o')" 
            domain="[('product_id', '=', parent.product_id)]" 
            groups="stock.group_production_lot" 
            context="{'default_product_id': parent.product_id, 'active_picking_id': picking_id}"/>
<field name="x_lot_qty" 
            attrs="{'readonly': ['&amp;', ('package_level_id', '!=', False), ('parent.picking_type_entire_packs', '=', True)]}" 
            invisible="not context.get('show_lots_m2o')" 
            domain="[('product_id', '=', parent.product_id)]" 
            groups="stock.group_production_lot" 
            context="{'default_product_id': parent.product_id, 'active_picking_id': picking_id}"/>
```

I did applied filter via domain attribute but it is not working. How can I restrict the lot numbers with quantity 0.

**UPDATE:**
I tried following solution:
I created a new dynamic selection field and tried populating the lots which are not empty with respect to location, below is the code:

```
@api.onchange('location_id')
def _fetch_non_empty_lots(self):
    lots = []
    for row in self:
        quants = self.env['stock.quant'].search([('location_id.id','=',row.location_id.id), ('product_id.id', '=', row.product_id.id), ('quantity', '>', 0)])
        for quant in quants:
            lots.append(quant)
            
    return lots

x_lot_id = fields.Selection(selection="_fetch_non_empty_lots", name="Non Empty Lots")
```

But now when I select a new location, I get following error:

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\virtual_odoo12\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo12\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\virtual_odoo12\Scripts\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\virtual_odoo12\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo12\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo12\Scripts\odoo\service\model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo12\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo12\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo12\Scripts\odoo\http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\virtual_odoo12\scripts\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 962, in call_kw
    return self._call_kw(model, method, args, kwargs)
  File "c:\virtual_odoo12\scripts\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo12\Scripts\odoo\api.py", line 759, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo12\Scripts\odoo\api.py", line 746, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo12\Scripts\odoo\models.py", line 5524, in onchange
    record._onchange_eval(name, field_onchange[name], result)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo12\Scripts\odoo\models.py", line 5369, in _onchange_eval
    process(method_res)
  File "C:\virtual_odoo12\Scripts\odoo\models.py", line 5355, in process
    if res.get('value'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

**UPDATE 2:**
Instead of modifying the existing dropdown, I created a dynamic dropdown. When location is selected, the drop down is populated with lot numbers which have quantity greater than 0. However, I am facing a basic issue/error:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Here is the model selection field and code to populate it:

```
@api.onchange('location_id')
def _fetch_non_empty_lots(self):
        quants = self.env['stock.quant'].search([('location_id.id','=',self.location_id.id), 
                        ('product_id.id', '=', self.product_id.id), 
                        ('quantity', '>', 0)])
        return {str(quant.lot_id.id) :str.title(quant.lot_id.display_name) for quant in quants} 

## declare field    

x_lot_id = fields.Selection(selection="_fetch_non_empty_lots", name="Non Empty Lots")
```

When the list is empty, there is no error. When there is non-empty lot then I am getting the eror. Ineed some assistance.

Comment: Did you try to define your field (stored to make it searchable) in the lot model?

Answer (score 1):

Odoo defines a product quantity field in the stock production lot model, you can use that field in the domain to filter lots, and you need to set `store` to `True` to make it searchable. If you need to define a new field then use the same logic and define it in the lot model to use in the `lot_id` field domain.

You got that error because Odoo expects a [dictionary](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/odoo/api.py#L184) and it got a list instead.

> The method may return a dictionary for changing field domains and pop up a warning message, like in the old API.

In your two last examples, you set the selection attribute to a string but the `selection` attribute specifies the possible values for this field. It is given as either a list of pairs (`value`, `string`), or a model method, or a method name. You can find an example in [website_customer](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/website_customer/models/res_partner.py#L21) module.

***Edit:*** (return a domain from `onchange` method)

The method may return a dictionary for changing field domains and pop up a warning message, like in the old API::

```
return {
    'domain': {'other_id': [('partner_id', '=', partner_id)]},
    'warning': {'title': "Warning", 'message': "What is this?"},
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate how I use the code because I followed the same logic as link i.e. 
[(quant.lot_id.display_name, str.title(quant.lot_id.display_name)) for quant in quants]
but getting same error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'"

Comment: You got that error because you returned a list and Odoo expects a dictionary. You need to remove the `onchange` decorator from the method that computes the selection value.

Comment: When I removed the onchange decorator, every time the selection method return empty value

Comment: however I changed return statement to   

{str(quant.lot_id.id) :str.title(quant.lot_id.display_name) for quant in quants}

but still getting empty data in return. I debugged with pdb, the function is called 4 times when I change location.At the 3rd function call I see data in self (stock.move.line) there my function works but when 4th time function is called, it returns no lots since self contains nothing

Comment: Of course `self` is an empty recordset, you can't use field values, they are not available yet.

Comment: I get stock.move.line with corresponding data in the row with the 3rd function call. How do I get data other than self object than ?

Comment: What did you change in your code, I checked the last one without the ``onchange`` decorator and the selection value is a function reference

Comment: I have edited my question, you can see the latest changes of my code in "UPDATE 2" section. I have used @api.onchange('location_id') to get current selected location

Comment: I have gone through the odoo.com community and found that I am unable to change the selections from onchange function. Instead I have to create the many2one instead of selection field and return the domain in the onchange. 

https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/change-selection-field-with-onchange-api-102465

Comment: But I am confused with the last statement how to return the domain in the onchange

Comment: Check my edit, I added the official source code documentation to return a domain from ``onchange`` method.

Comment: I tried that and added this code on change of location_id  
{'domain': {'lot_id': [('product_id', '=', 'parent.product_id'),('product_qty', '>', 0)]}} ... but getting empty lots in dropdown

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225683/discussion-between-user1584253-and-kenly).

Comment: That I have copied from the view (xml) file, and this is to restrict the lot number related to the product only. If I remove it, all lots will be displayed irrespective of the product selected

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like that?

```py
lot_id = fields.Many2one('stock.production.lot', 'Lot/Serial Number123' 
  domain="[('product_id', '=', parent.product_id),('product_qty', '>', 0)]" )
```

Comment: It's not working, the field x_lot_qty .. It is calculating the  quantity of product in lot number considering the location also ... I did something like this
         lot_id = fields.Many2one('stock.production.lot', 'Lot/Serial Number1234', 
                                domain="[('product_id', '=', parent.product_id),('x_lot_qty', '>', 0)]")

Comment: `x_lot_qty` is on the `stock.move.line` but you search from `stock.production.lot`

Comment: yes, because lot_id is not available in stock_move_line .. and my objective is to show only those lots which have product quantity greater than 0 with respect to location

Answer (score 0):

> What I understand is you want to show only those `lots` which have
> more than 0 products, in your lots drop down

You can try this in your **`XML`**

```
<field name="lot_id" 
            attrs="{'readonly': ['&amp;', ('package_level_id', '!=', False), ('parent.picking_type_entire_packs', '=', True)]}" 
            invisible="not context.get('show_lots_m2o')" 
            domain="[('product_qty', '>', 0)]"     //View this
            groups="stock.group_production_lot" 
            context="{'default_product_id': parent.product_id, 'active_picking_id': picking_id}"/>
```

Comment: It's not working ... one filter should be there every time ('product_id', '=', parent.product_id) .. otherwise it will show all products lot, then product_qty is not working since it contains total product quantity not by lot numbers therefore, I created a custom computed field named x_lot_qty so it sees which location is selected in "from" column and what product is selected then it shows the quantity. So we need to consider location also

Comment: I tried domain="[('product_id', '=', parent.product_id),('xlot_qty', '>', 0)]" but getting this error "ValueError: Invalid field 'xlot_qty' in leaf "<osv.ExtendedLeaf: ('xlot_qty', '>', 0) on stock_production_lot (ctx: )>""

Comment: You're trying `('xlot_qty', '>', 0)` but I'm saying `('product_qty', '>', 0)` try this my dear fellow :)

Comment: Hello @AdamStrauss, it not work because the field 'product_qty' of the stock.production.lot is the computed field and non-store field.

Comment: Oh got it, then what is the solution any guidance :)

Comment: I tried creating a dynamic dropdown that when location is selected then non empty lot numbers should be populated in the dropdown. But getting some error. I have updated my question, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

add this on your stock.move.line model:

```
@api.onchange('parent.product_id')
def _onchange_product_id(self):
    quants = self.env['stock.quant'].search([('product_id', '=', self.parent.product_id.id), ('quantity', '>', 0)])
    return {
        'domain': {
            'lot_id': [
                ('id', 'in', quants.lot_id.ids)
            ],
        },
    }
```

Comment: It is not working .. I changed the decorator parameter to @api.onchange('lot_id', 'location_id') ... and added location filter in stock.quant .. but no luck

Comment: No, don't change the onchange decorator params to 'lot_id' and 'location_id'. 
Can you make sure the onchange is being called?

Comment: Yes, when I change the decorator to location_id then it is called. Please see the screenshot, the product is already selected. However, when location changes then lots having quantity greater than 0 should be filtered only

Comment: the location_id is that 'From' field?, if so then change to @api.onchange('location_id'), if the function is called, then you need to check the result of 'quants.lot_id.ids', if 'quants.lot_id.ids' is not correct then problem is the search query.

Comment: I have  put additional filter in your query ... ('location_id.display_name','=', self.location_id.display_name) ... it give correct result .. but doesn't populate the dropdown

Comment: doesn't populate dropdown? you mean the dropdown is entirely empty?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227908/discussion-between-sdbot-and-user1584253).

Comment: try remove the onchange method, if the lot_id started to populate, then the domain returned by the onchange method is incorrect. But if the lot_id remain empty even after you removed the onchange method then either you have domain applied domain filter somewhere else, which you need to remove then try again.